# Can't find WinJS when creating new project

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, winjs, uwp

I'm pretty new to windows development, but I'm good at js. Since I would love to develop universal apps I did some research and found WinJs. I started to watch some microsoft's build conferences and tutorial on youtube but i can't find the winJs option and template in the "new project" window of visual studio. Any suggestion? please help me! I really want to start developing winjs apps! (also sorry for my bad english:) )

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps bellow：

1. Click "new project"
2. Click "Templates" in the new project window.
3. Click "Other Language"
4. Click "JavaScript" and chose "Blank App(Universal Windows)" , don't forget change your project name.

Please see my [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMGjd.png).